# R package in Dockerfile: couldn't find package 'tidyverse/googlesheets4'

Tags: r, docker, dockerfile, devtools, googlesheets4

I managed to install the following package on my local RStudio session:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/googlesheets4")
```

I am now trying to install it directly in the Dockerfile of my RStudio session on my server.
For that, below the line:

```
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('DT', 'shiny', 'DBI', 'devtools'))"
```

I have added:

```
RUN R -e "devtools::install_version('tidyverse/googlesheets4')"
```

But when I launch the `docker-compose up -d` command I get this error:

> Error in package_find_repo(package, repos) :   couldn't find package
>   'tidyverse/googlesheets4' Calls:  ...  ->
>   download_version_url -> package_find_repo Execution halted ERROR:
>   Service 'rstudio' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c R -e
>   "devtools::install_version('tidyverse/googlesheets4')"' returned a
>   non-zero code: 1

Do you know what could be the issue?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why are you running `install_github` locally but `install_version` in the docker? If you also ran `install_github` that should be fine. Also [googlesheets4 is not on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=googlesheets4) so you don't even need to use the github version unless you specifically need the dev version of the package.

Comment: I need the dev version because I need a specific function that was recently developed. So I should do instead in Dockerfile `RUN R -e "devtools::install_github('tidyverse/googlesheets4')"` ?

Comment: Yes. That should work.

Comment: I made a typo but you were faster than my correction. I am trying now. Thx

Comment: I got this error after doing `docker-compose up -d` >>> ERROR: Service 'rstudio' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c R -e "devtools::install_github('tidyverse/googlesheets4')"' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: Can you devtools::install_github for any other packages? Have you set up a proper build environment on that machine so devtools can work? What type of docker image is this?

Comment: This is my Dockerfile: `FROM rocker/tidyverse:3.6.1

RUN mkdir -p /rstudio
RUN mkdir -p /rscripts

RUN R -e "install.packages(c('Rselenium','httr','rvest','DBI','RPostgres','shiny','devtools'))"

RUN R -e "devtools::install_github('tidyverse/googlesheets4')"`